# MS - Access BigInt SQL SERVER Issues

Tags: sql, ms-access, biginteger

I have an access database that we use for simple reporting solutions, this pulls data from a remote data base through an ODBC link.  The data-warehouse provider has recently added a new data field to all of their tables which is formatted as a 'BIGINT'

Access now shows all records as deleted as it cannot deal with the BIGINT linked table.

As the data warehouse will not change their tables is there anyway that I can get the MS-Access to display correctly and ignore the 'BIGINT' field in the table linking?

I am having to work around this at this moment in time by copying the entire data warehouse minus this column to a MYSQL DB daily which is far from ideal...

I cannot for the life of me work this out.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a linked table, just write a passthru query in Access. Eventually `CONVERT` your BigInt into a string or Integer, depending on the contents.

Comment: A view might work, depending on how important the column is. It may also be important to add an index.

Answer (score 1):

This link suggests loading the data into a local table with a data type of string:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fb6f99ec-2ed7-487b-ba39-0777a0b44d5f/the-bigint-problem?forum=accessdev

Perhaps consider that MS Access's usefulness is limited here and it may pay to use SQL Server in future as you will continue to run into these kinds of problems. Is there any reason you can't use the datawarehouse directly?

You may also wish to consider using an .ADP (a file type of MS Access) which has a native OLE DB connection to the SQL Server database (no ODBC flimflammery) but also all the usual forms and reports.

ADP's are deprecated but I have had great success with them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, SQL server is I agree the best port of call the datawarehouse we use has almost everything that we do locked down and the reports that we can run directly are limited.  It comes into access as access is the simplest interface to link together the multitude of systems that we rely on.  SQL server doesn't allow the flexibility that access does.

Comment: I will look at the .ADP and if that doesn't work I am expecting to have to rework our entire solutions and build a brand new solution which whilst  this was the eventual aim is not what I would want to undertake right at this time...

Comment: As ADP runs on OLE DB not Jet, it would mostly be a rewrite on this platform any but take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but you can create a view and cast the bigint as int, and then Access will link to it.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but:

Casting your `bigint` as an `int` as someone has suggested isn't going to work if any of your values in your `bigint` column are bigger than the maximum value for an `int` (and if none of them are bigger than the max value for an `int`, it makes you wonder why a `bigint` is being used in the first place).

MS Access (from Access 2000 onward) does have a `decimal` data type, which is good for numbers of up to the maximum size of a SQL Server `bigint` and more.  So if you make your MS Access field to be of type `decimal`, it can handle anything a SQL Server `bigint` can throw at it.  In your process of taking the data from the SQL Server database into your MS Access database you would need something done programatically along the way to slurp your `bigint` values from SQL Server and squirt them into MS Access as `decimal`